# show values in input box if validation fails

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have repopulate the form when validation fails.I use php POST to for validation in same page.So i used

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['Name']; ?>"/>
```

When i open a new form it shows some html tags as value in input box and also say `SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for`

could anyone please help me sort out the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem by taking a glance is that you didn't close off the input element:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['Name']; ?>"/>
```